# In Keras how to get the `class_indices` or prediction labels for an existing model

Tags: keras, prediction

I know that keras provides a `.class_indicies` dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class as part of `.flow_from_directory()` from its `ImageDataGenerator` class  (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

However, is there a way to access the corresponding class labels from an existing *saved* model (a model saved in as an .h5 file)?  This seems important when putting my model into production and serving predictions since the classes are not known upfront and therefore the images are not separated in pre-labeled directories.

Answer (score 1):

It's in class_indices attributes of your train generator.

train_generator_example = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe,
    directory=None,
 .......
)

The labels can be obtained from a dictionary that is an attribute from "train_generator_example"

train_generator_example.class_indices.